# Trouble importing data using readr and setting column types

Tags: r, csv, import, readr

I was importing a csv file and trying to set some data types to factor as seen below, which were guessed to be character originally. I figure it would be helpful to set the correct data type when importing but am having trouble with the code.

```
> ADT_v3 <- read.csv(("ADT.v3.csv"),
+ col_types = cols(
+     pat_enc_csn_id = col_double(),
+     pat_mrn_id = col_double(),
+     PAT_NAME = col_character(),
+     HOSP_ADMSN_TIME = col_time(format = ""),
+     HOSP_DISCH_TIME = col_time(format = ""),
+     ADT_datetime = col_time(format = ""),
+     ADT_event_name = col_factor(levels = c("Admission", "Transfer Out", "Transfer In", "Patient Update", "Census")),
+     location = col_character(),
+     ROOM_ID = col_double(),
+     level_of_care = col_factor(levels = c("NULL", "Floor", "ICU", "Floor with Tele", "Intermediate/Stepdown"))
+ ))
```

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  unused argument (col_types = list(list(list(), list(), list(), list(""), list(""), list(""), list(c("Admission", "Transfer Out", "Transfer In", "Patient Update", "Census"), FALSE, FALSE), list(), list(), list(c("NULL", "Floor", "ICU", "Floor with Tele", "Intermediate/Stepdown"), FALSE, FALSE)), list(), NULL))
```

I've tried to make sure the code doesn't have typos or errors but....haven't had any luck identifying the problem.

Comment: Hi! Try using read_csv instead of read.csv (read_csv is from readr)

Comment: Thank you. I did not notice that! Also I have ended up using mutate AFTER reading it in and it seems more simple. Not entirely sure if the results produced are the same. I tried this method bc even with read_csv I was getting error message.

`> ADT_v3 |>
+     mutate(
+         ADT_event_name = factor(ADT_event_name),
+         level_of_care = factor(level_of_care),
+         location = factor(location)
+     )`

Comment: You're welcome!! You can select the columns after reading it by using `transmute(col=col_type)` with all the columns of interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ADT_v3 <- read_csv(("ADT.v3.csv"),
 col_types = cols(
     pat_enc_csn_id = col_double(),
     pat_mrn_id = col_double(),
     PAT_NAME = col_character(),
     HOSP_ADMSN_TIME = col_time(format = ""),
     HOSP_DISCH_TIME = col_time(format = ""),
     ADT_datetime = col_time(format = ""),
     ADT_event_name = col_factor(levels = c("Admission", "Transfer Out", "Transfer In", "Patient Update", "Census")),
     location = col_character(),
     ROOM_ID = col_double(),
     level_of_care = col_factor(levels = c("NULL", "Floor", "ICU", "Floor with Tele", "Intermediate/Stepdown"))
 ))
```

(only replaced `read.csv` by `readr::read_csv`)